# Error on initializing ribbon control in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, ribbon

I am using [ribbon control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx) in my wpf application. Upon running after pulling code in a different machine using github I encountered this error:

```
'Initialization of 'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonApplicationMenuItem' threw an exception.' Line number '15' and line position '26'.
```

My initial thought was that I have to install ribbon control on to my new machine manually, but when I checked using Nuget manager, it seems that ribbon control library is already installed.
Also there is no error in including the namespace `using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;`
Exception is only thrown when the window having ribbon control is loaded.

EDIT:
I cleaned the solution and re builded again. Now I Visual Studio is giving me error in error list which is :

```
Error   3   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Shell, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.   D:\Projects\WPFTut\Ribbons\MainWindow.xaml  12  13  Ribbons
```

I am pretty usre that I do not need to install the ribbon control because a previous running was running fine on this machine although there are no changes in any auto generated file since that commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Nuget is taking over the right component which needs to be installed. Please install Microsoft Ribbon from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877
and then close your application and build it again. It should work. If it doesn't then remove the reference of ribbon control and add once again the reference.

Comment: It is pretty late since then but I am accepting your answer because this is exactly what I did later to solve the problem.